# this.$emit is not a function within ajax success request

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the code below:

```
remove Dog: function(dog) {
self = this;
const updated = this.pets.filter(o => o !== dog);
    $.ajax({
        type: "PATCH",
        url: //irrelevant,
        'data': //irrelevant,
        'dataType': 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            self = this;
            this.$emit('update:pets', updated);
        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to have an emit command after the success of the ajax request. The ajax works fine so don't worry about that. I am just unable to do the emitting because it says that `this.$emit is not a function`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `this` doesn't point to what you think it does...

Answer (score 0):

`this` property has access to your scope level properties because it's a function and not an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). So when you access the properties or method which is not in the scope of that function, it returns undefined or not a function.

To fix it, Make your success function as an `arrow function` of Javascript.

```
success: (result) => {
            this.$emit('update:pets', updated);
        },
```

Another way is to remove the self inside the success method and use the outer `self`.

```
success: function (result) {
            self.$emit('update:pets', updated);
        },
```